# Does RadControls have an equivalent searchbox/filter like JqGrid?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jqgrid, rad-controls

The JqGrid search filter feature is what I am after with RadControls [enter any text into the 'ship name' search box](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx).

The closest I can see in the Telerik demos is [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/filteringcombo/defaultcs.aspx), but it gives a dropdown menu of all items in a list and is not built into the grid.

Answer (score 0):

This filtering looks closer to what you were looking for: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/filtering/defaultcs.aspx